# On keyup freezes other key events

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

The below code is working "properly" with just one issue. Whenever the keyup event is triggered, the target keys still keep responding to the any keyup or keydown events, while all other keys become non responsive. Seems like I'm missing some unbinding here but can't figure it out. I've tried `off()` and `unbind()`, but unsuccessfully.

What is intended is that if these keys are pressed, they do the triggering, but all other keys should not freeze.

```
var delta = 500; // time interval since the last keyup event
var lastKeypressTime = 0; // double enter flag set    
$( this ).on( "keyup", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        $(' a.left' ).css( "opacity", "0.5" ).trigger( 'click' );
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        $(' a.right' ).css( "opacity", "0.5" ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var thisKeypressTime = new Date();
        $( ' div div.active a.readon' ).focus();
        if (thisKeypressTime - lastKeypressTime <= delta)
        {
            $(' div div.active a.readon' )[0].click();
            thisKeypressTime = 0;
        }
        lastKeypressTime = thisKeypressTime;
    }
} );
```

Comment: What context is `this`? Is it the entire page? Does it include a very large number of elements in it's scope?

Comment: @DevlshOne thanks but suddenly I just figured it out. The event.preventDefault(); is not correctly positioned inside the method. By placing it inside the conditional check, keys no longer freeze and the others keep working as they should.

Comment: Well done. Depending on the size of the `this` scope, I was going to suggest `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Not sure if I should answer my question...

Comment: Sure, why not? If you've solved your own problem, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

So found the issue that was causing the unwanted behavior by moving the `event.preventDefault();` from before the conditional to inside it in the keys that default should be prevented.

```
var delta = 500; // time interval since the last keyup event
var lastKeypressTime = 0; // double enter flag set    
$( this ).on( "keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(' a.left' ).css( "opacity", "0.5" ).trigger( 'click' );
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(' a.right' ).css( "opacity", "0.5" ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var thisKeypressTime = new Date();
        $( ' div div.active a.readon' ).focus();
        if (thisKeypressTime - lastKeypressTime <= delta)
        {
            $(' div div.active a.readon' )[0].click();
            thisKeypressTime = 0;
        }
        lastKeypressTime = thisKeypressTime;
    }
} );
```